# Overriding loadView causes viewDidLoad and loadView to fire everytime a VC appears

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, uiviewcontroller, subclass

My view heirarchy sits on several custom "root" UIViewController subclasses. I'm trying to set a custom self.view for one of my root VC subclasses. There, I am doing:

**MyRootViewController_With_Scroll.h**

```
// Import lowest level root VC
#import "MyRootViewController.h"
// my custom scroll view I want to use as self.view
@class MyScrollView;

@interface MyRootViewController_With_Scroll : MyRootViewController {

}

@property (strong) MyScrollView *view;

@end
```

**MyRootViewController_With_Scroll.m**

```
#import MyRootViewController_With_Scroll.h;

@interface MyRootViewController_With_Scroll ()

@end

@implementation MyRootViewController_With_Scroll

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)loadView
{
    NSLog(@"loading view");
    CGRect windowSize = [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame;
    MyScrollView *rootScrollView = [MyScrollView scrollerWithSize:windowSize.size];
    self.view = rootScrollView;

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// Getter and setter for self.view
- (MyScrollView *)view
{
    return (MyScrollView *)[super view];
}
- (void)setView:(MyScrollView *)view
{
    [super setView:view];
}
```

According to the iOS6 docs, viewDidLoad in only suppose to fire once per view controller for the entire lifecycle of the app.

What am I doing wrong here? What is causing my view controllers to repeatedly call loadView/viewDidLoad? Strangely, my apps "home screen" VC loads the view just once, but all its subsequent views in the navigation heirachy fires loadView everytime they appear. What is going on?

**edit** I've changed the property to `strong`. Same issue happens.

**edit 2** I've stopped overriding loadView and its still happening. Now I'm really confused.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight changed the property to strong and same issue occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behaviour. If you're popping view controllers off a navigation stack, and nothing else has a reference to them, then they're going to get deallocated. Therefore when it appears again, it will be a new instance, so it has to perform `loadView` and so on all over again. Include `self` in your logging, you should see that it is a different object each time.

You've also redefined the view controller's view property as `weak` - if you *are* re-using the view controller objects, then this will be nilled out as soon as the view has no superview.

Prior to iOS 6, a view controller that was mid-way in your navigation stack would get its view unloaded under memory pressure:

```
root --> VC1 --> VC2
```

VC2 is on screen, a memory warning is received. VC1 would unload its view. When you pop VC2 off the stack, VC1 would call `loadView` again. This no longer happens.

However, if you've popped back to VC1, and nothing has a strong reference to VC2, then VC2 is deallocated. When you push another VC2 onto the stack, this is a new instance and `loadView` will be called again. Presumably you are creating these new instances of VC2 in code, so you should be able to tell that you are creating a new instance.

Comment: I've changed the property to strong and the same issue occurs. According to the docs, in iOS6 viewDidLoad is not supposed to fire more than once because viewDidUnload never gets fired. Is there something I'm doing which causes iOS to think that self.view is always missing when a VC appears?

Comment: It fires once _per instance_ of each view controller. I believe you are creating new instances every time you push onto the navigation stack.

Comment: That would explain why my home screen correctly gets viewDidLoad called only once. I hope someone is able to pipe up here and confirm thats the case. Its pretty confusing that NavCon gives the appearance of a different behavior after how much emphasis the iOS6 docs put on "viewDidUnload never get's called and viewDidLoad gets called only once"

Comment: I've added some extra information. You don't show in your question how you are pushing new view controllers onto the stack, but if you're implementing loadView then presumably you're creating them in code?

Comment: Yes, I'm doing this all with code, no storyboard or nibs. I'm pushing my VCs onto a nav controller. I thought that UINavigationController keeps references to the VCs...

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that UINavigationController keeps absolutely no strong references to any its VCs? It doesn't manage them at all except to present them and pop them?

Comment: It keeps strong references to all the VCs in the current navigation stack. Once you've popped one off the top, it's gone.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I've really learned a lot today. I feel like this info should be a bit more clear in the iOS6 docs.

Answer (score 0):

Thats because you have weak view property. So it get realloced all the time. Also, I don't think that you need to override view property at all.

Comment: Changed the property to strong. Same issue occurs. If I don't override the view property, then its still cast to UIView, which is not the class I'm using.

Comment: so cast it to whatever class you need where you use it. I don't see any point for overriding view property.